# Gradle-Eclipse- How to ensure Referenced libraries dont get removed on gradle refresh

Tags: gradle

I have set up Gradle project on Eclipse
When  I do Run as 'Gradle Test', I get the jars added in "Project and External Dependencies" based on entries in build.gradle.
However the referenced libraries added earlier by"Add as External jars' are not present.
How do I ensure that this does not happen.

Answer (score 0):

All dependencies should be added in `build.gradle`. This makes sense, you don't want things working in Eclipse and failing from Gradle command line.

Anything added via "Add as External jars" will be overridden